# Parameterised query in kdb dashboard

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to use a drop-down list in a Kx dashboard which returns the columns from the database:

[image]

Then I want to use this in a select query in a line chart but only the text is returned, not the values:

[image]

These are the selected value states:

[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashboards is part of the enterprise solutions offered by Kx. This forum is not the correct place to be seeking assistance with Dashboard related issues, you should contact your support contact within Kx for help on this.

The use of Dashboards is not really a kdb issue here, it is dependent on your configuration, version of the Platform, version of kdb, processes you have running, version of java etc etc etc. It would not feasible for someone outside of your support stack to assist with this.